# Add data from array to picker component

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, nsarray

In my application i am using picker control,

I want to get the data from array  to my picker view,

Array comes like this,

```
 PickerArray:(
    {
    CustEmail = test@test.com;
    CustFirstName = ABC;
    CustID = 1;
    CustLastName = Test;
    CustPhoneNo = 12345;
    }
```

My picker has one component,

```
 - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
NSString *title;

title = [[PickerArray objectAtIndex:row]valueForKey:@"CustFirstName"];
NSLog(@"title:%@",title);

return title;
```

}

with this I am getting just one value If i want to get CustFirstName and Email in one row of picker component. 
Like **ABC  test@test.com;**

Please any one suggest how can i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `stringWithFormat:` to construct composite strings, like this:

```
title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@"
,   [[PickerArray objectAtIndex:row]valueForKey:@"CustFirstName"]
,   [[PickerArray objectAtIndex:row]valueForKey:@"CustEmail"]
];
```

Answer (score 2):

Compose string according to requirement:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{
  NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[[PickerArray objectAtIndex:row]valueForKey:@"CustFirstName"],[[PickerArray objectAtIndex:row]valueForKey:@"CustEmail"]];
 NSLog(@"title:%@",title);

 return title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[[PickerArray objectAtIndex:row]valueForKey:@"CustFirstName"],[[PickerArray objectAtIndex:row]valueForKey:@"CustEmail"]];
```